# How to replace all spaces which are not actually spaces with regex in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, character-set

I have the following string which I want to 'clean' from multiple whitespaces:

```
$string = "This is   a test string"; //Using utf8_decode
```

Not a big deal right? However, the string is not 'cleaned' after using:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

Because, the string actually is like this:

```
$test = "This is a Â test string";
```

So, how can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

***Please, I don't want to replace the Â character like `str_replace('Â', '')` or something***

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $string)`

Comment: Lol hero's are fast right? thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not a unicode guy so for my info, how is `Â` a whitespace charcter?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: It is not a whitespace character, it is a char that some Unicode whitespace char turned into after converting into a different encoding.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `/u` UNICODE modifier:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $string);
```

> The [`/u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) enables the PCRE engine to handle strings as UTF8 strings (by turning on `PCRE_UTF8` verb) and make the shorthand character classes in the pattern Unicode aware (by enabling  `PCRE_UCP` verb)

The main point is that `\s` will now match all Unicode whitespace and the input string is treated as a Unicode string.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to fix this for hours.